# Difference between @inject and @mock annotations

Tags: gwt, junit, mockito, guice, gwt-gin

In the Context of JUnit, what is the difference between @inject and @mock, and in which conditions both can be used?

thanks,
Rohit

Comment: If you want to use both annotations in your tests, you might want to have a look at https://github.com/ArcBees/Jukito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Inject
```

... is an annotation which is defined in Guice and is quite simliar to Spring **@Autowire**. You can use these Annotations to inject a Object which you whant to use in your tests (i.e. persistence context to work with jpa)

```
@Mock
```

... is an annotation to (more or less) inject mock objects into your test class. In the method annoteted with **@Before** you can initialize the @Mock annoteted attributes via MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this). Another way you can go is to  annotate the testclass with **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)**.

I hope this will help for the first steps ;-)

Comment: or add a mockito rule